# How to parse json array with ajax?

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets

Servlet side. I write 2 JSON `String` objects to JSON array:

```
Gson data = new Gson();
JsonArray arr = new JsonArray();

JsonObject obj1 = new JsonObject();
JsonElement element = data.toJsonTree(imgstr);
obj1.add("image", element);
arr.add(obj1);

JsonObject obj2 = new JsonObject();
JsonElement element1 = data.toJsonTree(strBuf);
obj2.add("html", element1);
arr.add(obj2);

out.write(arr.toString());
```

Ajax. I receive that array:

```
done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
})
```

It shows `[{"image":"myImageString"},{"html":"myHtmlString"}]`.

How to get that Strings separately? Following doesn't work:

```
var image=result.image;
var html=result.html;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result in this case in an *array* of objects. So you should acces them as an array:

```
var image=result[0].image;
var html=result[1].html;
```

It would be better though to just return **one** object:

```
                    JsonObject obj1 = new JsonObject();
                    JsonElement element = data.toJsonTree(imgstr);
                    obj1.add("image", element);
                    obj1.add("html", element1

                    out.write(obj1.toString());
```

In which case your suggested code

```
var image=result.image;
var html=result.html;
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

if you sending an array, you must retrieve objects from array by index like

```
var image=result[0].image;
```

But if you want to get objects by name like

```
var image=result.image;
```

you must send `JsonObject` not a `JsonArray`